# MySQL LIKE keyword Multiple Columns but Which Column Queried?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two scripts below. The first script only searches one Column for a user-typed keyword, then it will display the results as a list and make BOLD the characters the user typed. That script works great.

The second script is something I modified to search multiple columns. It searches just fine. The problem is that I cannot get the BOLD (or make STRONG) if the searched value came from the other columns. How do I determine if the searched value came for Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, etc...? If the searched value came from column "DESCRIP" then I want to make the letter bold in the listed value.

First Script:

```
<?php
   require_once("../config.php");
   $keyword = '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%';
   $rootval = $_POST['rval'];
   $sql = "SELECT `ID`,`MUNTERS_PN`,`DESCRIP`, `IMG_PATH`, `MANUF`, `MANUF_PN` FROM `electrical_parts` WHERE `MUNTERS_PN` LIKE (:keyword) ORDER BY `MUNTERS_PN` ASC LIMIT 0, 5";
   $query = $db_qms->prepare($sql);
   $query->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $query->execute();
   $list = $query->fetchAll();
   foreach ($list as $rs) {

          // put in bold the written text
      $partnum = str_replace($_POST['keyword'], '<span style="font-weight:700;font-size:14px;">'.$_POST['keyword'].'</span>', $rs['MUNTERS_PN']);

          // add new option
      echo '<li class="set_part"  data-val="' . $rs['ID'] . '"><a href="' . $rootval . 'pages/show_part.php?t=electrical_parts&p=' . $rs['ID'] . '" class="part_link"><img src="' . $rootval . '../parts/' . $rs['IMG_PATH'] . '" width="100px;" style="padding-right:15px;">'.$partnum.'<span style="font-style:italic;font-size:13px;padding-left:10px;">[' . $rs['MANUF'] . ': ' . $rs['MANUF_PN'] . '] <br/>' . $rs['DESCRIP'] . '</span></a></li>';

   }
?>
```

Second Script:

```
<?php
   require_once("../config.php");
   $keyword = '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%';
   $rootval = $_POST['rval'];
   $sql = "SELECT `ID`,`MUNTERS_PN`,`DESCRIP`, `IMG_PATH`, `MANUF`, `MANUF_PN` FROM `electrical_parts` WHERE (`MUNTERS_PN` LIKE (:keyword) OR `DESCRIP` LIKE (:keyword) OR `MANUF` LIKE (:keyword) OR `MANUF_PN` LIKE (:keyword) ) ORDER BY `MUNTERS_PN` ASC LIMIT 0, 5";
   $query = $db_qms->prepare($sql);
   $query->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $query->execute();
   $list = $query->fetchAll();
     foreach ($list as $rs) {

           /******* INSERT CODE TO DETERMINE WHICH COLUMN WAS QUERIED ******/           

            // put in bold the written text
        $partnum = str_replace($_POST['keyword'], '<span style="font-weight:700;font-size:14px;">'.$_POST['keyword'].'</span>', $rs['MUNTERS_PN']);
        $manuf = str_replace($_POST['keyword'], '<span style="font-weight:700;font-size:14px;">'.$_POST['keyword'].'</span>', $rs['MANUF']);
        $manuf_pn = str_replace($_POST['keyword'], '<span style="font-weight:700;font-size:14px;">'.$_POST['keyword'].'</span>', $rs['MANUF_PN']);
        $descrip = str_replace($_POST['keyword'], '<span style="font-weight:700;font-size:14px;">'.$_POST['keyword'].'</span>', $rs['DESCRIP']);
            // add new option
        echo '<li class="set_part"  data-val="' . $rs['ID'] . '"><a href="' . $rootval . 'pages/show_part.php?t=electrical_parts&p=' . $rs['ID'] . '" class="part_link"><img src="' . $rootval . '../parts/' . $rs['IMG_PATH'] . '" width="100px;" style="padding-right:15px;">'.$partnum.'<span style="font-style:italic;font-size:13px;padding-left:10px;">[' . $rs['MANUF'] . ': ' . $rs['MANUF_PN'] . '] <br/>' . $rs['DESCRIP'] . '</span></a></li>';
     }
?>
```

Comment: I added variables `$manuf`, `$manuf_pn`, `$descrip` to make bold, but this script still doesn't work (the second script)

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, in the echo in the second script, you use $rs['MANUF'], $rs['MANUF_PN'] and $rs['DESCRIP'] instead of $manuf, $manuf_pn and $descrip.
That is why the replacements don't appear in the output.

So you should use :

```
echo '<li class="set_part"  data-val="' . $rs['ID'] . '"><a href="' . $rootval . 'pages/show_part.php?t=electrical_parts&p=' . $rs['ID'] . '" class="part_link"><img src="' . $rootval . '../parts/' . $rs['IMG_PATH'] . '" width="100px;" style="padding-right:15px;">'.$partnum.'<span style="font-style:italic;font-size:13px;padding-left:10px;">[' . $rs['MANUF'] . ': ' . $manuf_pn . '] <br/>' . $descrip . '</span></a></li>';
```

Comment: Good catch. But for some reason it still doesn't work.